# Как объединить эти JSON по значению?

Tags: php, json

Есть такой items.json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Fluted Guard of the Moon Rider",
    "icon": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcU_oAlcQk2fVOiSxMfcRlFwIBYYpbaaOA9vxv_MdC8M7tq0xoaOzvb2Z7iJxD8GsJIi0--Up9Sh0A2yr0pvZ22iJdXGdVQ5NUaQpAZGHIGG2g"
  },
  {
    "name": "Lion Quiver of the Moon Rider",
    "icon": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcU_oAlcQk2fVOiSxtraRVhmahdbiauwIhFlwb2aImoS7oWwzIPYwqetYeKExm9SsMAg3b7AoNz32QDkqUNtMD2lJdPGbEZgNjYx8IO6"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bow of the Moon Rider",
    "icon": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcU_oAlcQk2fVOiS1cDEHE54GgZYofT2e1cwgKWRc2pB74SyzNbYwfamZL6BwjgF65wn3eyRp96sjVbg_xFofSmtc2nZXSY6"
  }
]
```

И вот такой price.json:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
          "updated_at": 1576048969000,
          "prices": {
            "last": 5300
          },
          "name": "Lion Quiver of the Moon Rider"
        },
        {
          "updated_at": 1576048969000,
          "prices": {
            "last": 2000.12
          },
          "name": "Dragon Sheild"
        }
    ]
}
```

Как мне сопоставить цены из price.json по названию предмета?
Чтоб получилось вот так:

```
{
    "name": "Lion Quiver of the Moon Rider",
    "icon": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcU_oAlcQk2fVOiSxtraRVhmahdbiauwIhFlwb2aImoS7oWwzIPYwqetYeKExm9SsMAg3b7AoNz32QDkqUNtMD2lJdPGbEZgNjYx8IO6",
   "price":5300
  }
```

Пробовал делать вот так, но в результате дубликаты предметов и на которых нет цены удаляются:

```
<?php

$jsonProducts = '[
  {
    "name": "Fluted Guard of the Moon Rider",
    "icon": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcU_oAlcQk2fVOiSxMfcRlFwIBYYpbaaOA9vxv_MdC8M7tq0xoaOzvb2Z7iJxD8GsJIi0--Up9Sh0A2yr0pvZ22iJdXGdVQ5NUaQpAZGHIGG2g"
  },
  {
    "name": "Lion Quiver of the Moon Rider",
    "icon": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcU_oAlcQk2fVOiSxtraRVhmahdbiauwIhFlwb2aImoS7oWwzIPYwqetYeKExm9SsMAg3b7AoNz32QDkqUNtMD2lJdPGbEZgNjYx8IO6"
  },
  {
    "name": "Lion Quiver of the Moon Rider",
    "icon": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcU_oAlcQk2fVOiSxtraRVhmahdbiauwIhFlwb2aImoS7oWwzIPYwqetYeKExm9SsMAg3b7AoNz32QDkqUNtMD2lJdPGbEZgNjYx8IO6"
  }
  ]';

$jsonData = '{
    "data": [
        {
          "updated_at": 1576048969000,
          "prices": {
            "last": 5300
          },
          "name": "Lion Quiver of the Moon Rider"
        },
        {
          "updated_at": 1576048969000,
          "prices": {
            "last": 2000.12
          },
          "name": "T-shirts"
        }
    ]
}';

$data = json_decode($jsonData, true)['data'];

$products = array_column(json_decode($jsonProducts, true), null, 'name');

$result = array_map(function($item) use ($products) {
    $product              = new \stdClass();
    $product->market_name = $products[$item['name']]['name'];
    $product->size        = $products[$item['name']]['size'];
    $product->price       = $item['prices']['last'] ?? null;
    return $product;
}, $data);

$resultJson = json_encode($result);

var_dump($resultJson);
```

Comment: А можете дать полный пример результата, который вы хотите?

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive я указал пример нужного результата:                                      

`{
    "name": "Lion Quiver of the Moon Rider",
    "icon": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcU_oAlcQk2fVOiSxtraRVhmahdbiauwIhFlwb2aImoS7oWwzIPYwqetYeKExm9SsMAg3b7AoNz32QDkqUNtMD2lJdPGbEZgNjYx8IO6",
   "price":5300
  }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то можно сделать следующим образом:

```
$price = json_decode($jsonData, 1)['data'];
$json = json_decode($jsonProducts, 1);

foreach($price as $key => $value)
{
    foreach($json as $k => $value2) {
        if ($value['name'] === $value2['name']) {
            $json[$k]['price'] = $value['prices']['last'];
        }
    }
}

print_r($json);
```

https://3v4l.org/mWaIS

Если же вы хотите сделать `price` только для первого найденого вхождения (если рассматривать дубликаты), то можете сделать так:

```
$bool = false;
foreach($price as $key => $value)
{
    foreach($json as $k => $value2) {
        if ($value['name'] === $value2['name']) {
            if ($bool !== true) {
                $json[$k]['price'] = $value['prices']['last'];
                $bool = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/X7FoM

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$main='{"data1":[
  {
    "name": "Fluted Guard of the Moon Rider",
    "icon": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcU_oAlcQk2fVOiSxMfcRlFwIBYYpbaaOA9vxv_MdC8M7tq0xoaOzvb2Z7iJxD8GsJIi0--Up9Sh0A2yr0pvZ22iJdXGdVQ5NUaQpAZGHIGG2g"
  },
  {
    "name": "Lion Quiver of the Moon Rider",
    "icon": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcU_oAlcQk2fVOiSxtraRVhmahdbiauwIhFlwb2aImoS7oWwzIPYwqetYeKExm9SsMAg3b7AoNz32QDkqUNtMD2lJdPGbEZgNjYx8IO6"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bow of the Moon Rider",
    "icon": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcU_oAlcQk2fVOiS1cDEHE54GgZYofT2e1cwgKWRc2pB74SyzNbYwfamZL6BwjgF65wn3eyRp96sjVbg_xFofSmtc2nZXSY6"
  }
]
}';

 $go='{
    "data": [
        {
          "updated_at": 1576048969000,
          "prices": {
            "last": 5300
          },
          "name": "Lion Quiver of the Moon Rider"
        },
        {
          "updated_at": 1576048969000,
          "prices": {
            "last": 2000.12
          },
          "name": "Dragon Sheild"
        }
    ]
}';

$result=json_decode($main,true);
//print_r($result);
$result1=json_decode($go,true);
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {

    foreach ($result1 as $key0 => $value0) {
foreach ($value0 as $key10 => $value10) {

if($value1['name']==$value10['name']){

    $arr['price']=$value10['prices']['last'];
    $arr['icon']=$value1['icon'];
    $arr['name']=$value1['name'];
}

}
}

}
}

print_r($arr);
```